# Add Glossary to Google translte V3 API by python

Tags: csv, google-translate, glossary

I am trying to add a glossary by CSV. I put the CSV on my google storage. I got this Error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Failed to parse content of input file. Error: Not enough valid languages in CSV file. Must have terms for at least two different languages. num_valid_languages_in_csv = 0
```

my CSV is super simple. I made sure I save in utf-8. I also added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of my code.

```
Liz, 栗子
Tom, 汤姆
Nancy，楠西
```

The code is copied from the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encounter your error when using the CSV you provided. This is because the CSV file used does not have a header.

[image]

To fix this just add a header on your CSV file. Make sure you match the headers with your language code defined in your code.

**test_glossary_1.csv:**

```
en,zh
Liz, 栗子
Tom, 汤姆
Nancy，楠西
```

Create a glossary using the CSV with headers:
[image]

Check glossary if created:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Ricco! I also tried to add the launguages on the headers, which didn't work. I used zh-CN. I changed to zh, it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a good answer. Really weird that Google Translate's docs specified otherwise. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#translate_v3_translate_text_with_glossary-python

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the  link

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/vcc_translation/glossory_01.csv
```

**Now, to make this work, re-write the same as follows:**

```
gs://vcc_translation/glossory_01.csv
```

Where:

- `gs://` added from your side
- `vcc_translation` is the storage bucket